# Jquery Li Image Gallery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins, css, html-lists

How would I hide all li from a ul which were not the one on top.

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/mSmbv/375/

I need the li at the top to be the only one hidden.  All others should be hidden until they slide up into view and the top slide to the bottom.

Edit: I've gotten to the point where I can have them slide in and out but I would prefer a nice looking fade in/out where both current nad next li fade into each other. http://jsfiddle.net/mSmbv/386/

Comment: Hi @MCG.  This is more like asking someone to write a script for your code.  You may get a response.  But it would be a lot of work for someone.  What jQuery have you tried?  Give us an example?  Also, have you tried to Google "jQuery Image Gallery" or something similar, say http://is.gd/fdQS0T

Comment: Hi Jason,
I've only tried easySlider 1.7 and so was hoping anyone could maybe recommend well support and documented Jquery galleries that would fit the code above.  I know it would not be fair to expect someone to write the script when there are many others that are well supported across browsers, etc.  I simply am looking for scripts that might work based on my needs/code.

Comment: edit: the most simplest form of the script can simply be something which rotates the Li's of a ul where only the current li is shown and then ater x seconds, the next li replaces the previous and this becomes a continuos cycle.
Similar to http://jsfiddle.net/mSmbv/ but only 1 li is shown at a time.

Comment: edit #2: I have updated my question with the code and a simple question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your current code, I'd employ using the CSS3 selector.

```
#rotated li
{
    display: none;
}

#rotated li:nth-child(1)
{
    display: list-item;
}
```

I would try something along those lines.  You can also use jQuery to transition your CSS effects in and out of existence. Worst case you can iterate through the collection of LIs by specifying an !important CSS class that forces display and the style you're looking for.

Good luck!